# How do I set the dynamic properties on PublishKafka_2_0 processor in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using the PublishKafka_2_0 processor and need to disable SSL endpoint identification algorithm while connecting to Kafka. From the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#id1) I can do this by setting the following producer property to an empty string:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

The documentation of PublishKafka_2_0 mentions that this can be set using dynamic properties. Can someone show how to set this property? A screenshot or link to an example would be great.

I am using NiFi 1.9.1  and Apache Kafka 2.1.1

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I *strongly* discourage disabling endpoint verification, to accomplish this, click the **+** icon on the top right of the processor properties tab, enter the value `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` for the dynamic property name, and check the "Empty string" box for the value of the property.

I only took a quick look, but I do not see that property defined in the `ProducerConfig` class in the `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar` dependency. If the predefined string is not present, you may get a validation error in NiFi of "Must be a known configuration parameter for this kafka client".

Comment: Andy, thank you for the word of caution there on disabling this verification. We have a plant to enable it back as soon as we figure out a few logistical issues.